# Why does the Windows Store app use the GPU when checking for updates?

Tags: windows, windows-store-app

Start the Store app (Windows 10) and then click on "Get Updates".

Check the GPU tab in Task Manager and see under "3D" that it rises from 0% to around 10%. It stays at 10% while it's checking, so it's not just the window appearing.

This is on an onboard GPU of an Intel i5 9600K if this matters.

Comment: To display its window ?

Comment: Is there some animation while the check is in progress? That would cause some minor GPU load, because many apps nowadays are GPU-accelerated.

Comment: @harrymc I updated the question. It stays at 10% while checking for updates.

Comment: @DanielB As you can check on your computer, it has a minimal turning icon. Perhaps that is the reason, but it seems like too much gpu use for such a minor thing. But who knows, maybe that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While "Get Updates" is working, I see this blue circle spinning
continuously, and my own GPU is also working and using up a few
percents.

The answer is then the continuous drawing of the spinning blue circle,
which is the "I'm working" indicator of the Store.